# How to define an incomplete enum in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to define a property that could be one of the values of an enum or other string. I do not want to define the property as a string without an enum and I do not want to put into the enum an `OTHER` value.

Definition of a property 'p':

```
"p": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

I want it:

```
{
    "p": "D"
}
```

to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `oneOf` keyword: [understanding-json-schema/reference/combining](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id7)

One schema branch contains your `enum`, the other maype `pattern` ([more here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#id6)) if there is a valid regular expression to define any "other" values.